# Mongoose .save() not working inside Node/Express backend API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

```js
PostsRouter.post("/ALL", (req, res) => {
  const { subreddit, title, user, body } = req.body;
  const post = new PostMessage({
    postID: uuidv4(),
    subreddit: subreddit,
    title: title,
    user: user,
    body: body,
  });
  console.log(post);
  async function _internal() {
    try {
      const newPost = await post.save();
      res.status(201).json(newPost);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400);
    }
  }
  _internal();
});
```

This function exactly as it is was working earlier but now this method and another PATCH method I defined elsewhere are failing because the promise is never fulfilled on the first line of the try block that saves the new data to the database "const newPost = await post.save()". Would anyone know what could be causing an issue like this? When I make a call to this API there are no error messages from the backend. I also included an image showing how I am making the POST request and the error I am getting.  [image: Postman POST request]

Comment: Any reason you're creating and executing the `_internal` function instead of just making the entire route handler `async`?

Comment: I didn't realize I could make the entire route handler async before, but doing that doesn't change anything if I try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a document in the database and use that document for any further operations then you can use the below code for that purpose.

```
PostsRouter.post("/ALL", async(req, res) => {
      const { subreddit, title, user, body } = req.body;
      try {
        // PostMessage is the Model
        const newPost = await PostMessage.create({
          postID: uuidv4(),
          subreddit: subreddit,
          title: title,
          user: user,
          body: body,
      });
        console.log(newPost);
        res.status(201).json(newPost);
      }catch (error) {
        res.status(400);
      }
      }
    });
```

Hope this helps.